# Installing RedCloth gem from github with bundler

Tags: git, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1, redcloth, gemspecs

I'm running into a problem with the latest versioned release of the RedCloth gem, 4.2.7.  Specifically, it's the gcc 4.6 compile issue that was resolved in [this commit](https://github.com/jgarber/redcloth/commit/6e042c3fae6cf58b4b193fe076aa1cdc2e0a9b0b), but has not yet been included in a release despite how long ago it was committed.

In my Gemfile, I changed this:

```
gem 'RedCloth', '4.2.7'
```

to this:

```
gem 'RedCloth', :git => 'git://github.com/jgarber/redcloth.git'
```

However, when I run `bundle install`, I end up getting a warning message that reads:

```
RedCloth at /Users/mhuggins/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@myapp/bundler/gems/redcloth-9d6d28f93b02 did not have a valid gemspec.
This prevents bundler from installing bins or native extensions, but that may not affect its functionality.
The validation message from Rubygems was:
  ["ext/redcloth_scan/redcloth_attributes.c", "ext/redcloth_scan/redcloth_inline.c", "ext/redcloth_scan/redcloth_scan.c"] are not files
```

It looks like [this line](https://github.com/jgarber/redcloth/blob/master/redcloth.gemspec#L36) of the redcloth.gemspec is attempting to include 3 files that don't exist in the source tree, which is what's causing the error.

Anyone know what's going on here for me?  I must be missing a step or something.  (I'm on OS X using Rails 3.1 edge.)

Comment: It looks like those files are generated using Ragel before the gem is created. You might need to create a local clone of Redcloth and compile it yourself.

Comment: Is that easy to do with bundler/capistrano?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit fiddly, but I was able to get the git version of the Gemfile working on mac os x snow leopard with the following...

In your project:

```
bundle install
```

You get the error message like:

```
RedCloth at /Users/kunzmann/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bundler/gems/redcloth-9d6d28f93b02 did not have a valid gemspec.
```

Then you can do this if you have Ragel 6.3 or greater (I used `brew install Ragel`)

```
cd /Users/kunzmann/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bundler/gems/redcloth-9d6d28f93b02
bundle install
bundle exec rake compile
```

The next time you `bundle install` in your project you should see:

```
Using RedCloth (4.2.7) from git://github.com/jgarber/redcloth.git (at master) with native extensions
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running "bundle config build.RedCloth --with-cflags=-w" & then "bundle install".